# Laravel @foreach and @forelse

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem with my view of laravel. I have a field that executes a loop, and if it has data in the field it list, but if it does not it only shows me nothing.

I used `@forelse` but it does not work, any help?

with `$prices` I can check whether or not it has the value, but in that field`infos_home` does not.
I used @forelse but it does not work, any help?

```
<em>{{ $prices->price ?? ' - ' }}</em> <br>

@forelse($prices->infos_home as $info)
    <em>{{ $info }}</em> <br>
@empty
    <em> - </em>
@endforelse
```

When I use @forelse I have the following error message.

```
message: "Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Trying to get property 'infos_home' of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\suzuki-cms-backoffice\resources\views\brand\motorcycle\variations\index\column-price.blade.php)"
```

Comment: could you `dd($prices)`?

Comment: Yep.
When the data already has the `infos_home` field with values, in the loop it works, the problem is when I create empty it returns me an error

Comment: result dd($prices->infos_home)


```array:3 [
  0 => "freight_included"
  1 => "freight_country"
  2 => "freight_conditional"
]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KISS and just use `@if / @else`:

```php
<em>{{ $prices->price ?? ' - ' }}</em> <br>

@if($prices && $prices->infos_home)
    @foreach($prices->infos_home as $info)
        <em>{{ $info }}</em> <br>
    @endforeach
@else
    <em> - </em>
@endif
```

`@forelse` is good when you are sure that variable exists.

Comment: @forelse is good when you are sure that variable exists. got it

It worked, Thanks a lot, I love you! hehe